# How to show current location of mobile with street, city and country

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, geolocation

Following is the code i have written to get the current location of the mobile.It shows current location with the city and country of the mobile.But I need to display the street address location.
    Please advice as soon as possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;height=device-height; user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>PhoneGap Reverse Geolocation Lookup</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
$(document).ready(function() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
$('#button-get-reverse-lookup').click(function(){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGetCurrentPositionSuccess, onGetCurrentPositionError);
});
});
var onGetCurrentPositionSuccess = function(position) {
console.log("lat: " + position.coords.latitude);
console.log("long: " + position.coords.longitude);
var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude);
var lng = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);
// paris, france - uncomment to test
//var lat = parseFloat(48.850258);
//var lng = parseFloat(2.351074);
// tiburon, california
//var lat = parseFloat(37.872685);
//var lng = parseFloat(-122.45224);
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status)
{
 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                {
                    if (results[1])
                    {
                        var reverse_geo = results[1];

                         if (reverse_geo.address_components[0])
                          { 

                          alert(reverse_geo.address_components[4].long_name+"," + reverse_geo.address_components[3].long_name+"," + reverse_geo.address_components[2].long_name+"," + reverse_geo.address_components[0].long_name);
                          //text = text + "0: " + reverse_geo.address_components[0].long_name + "<br />"1: " + reverse_geo.address_components[1].long_name + "<br />""; 
                          }
                       }
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("No hay informaci�n de Reverse Geocoding.");
                }
});
}
var onGetCurrentPositionError = function(error) {
console.log("Couldn't get geo coords from device");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Reverse Geolocation Lookup</h1>
<button id="button-get-reverse-lookup">Get Reverse Lookup</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs on Google site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) you would need to loop through all the address components looking at the types and comparing them against what you wanted to extract.

street_number = Street Number
route = Street Name
locality = City
administrative_area_level_1 = State or Province
country = Country

There is no guarantee of the order in which the address components are delivered so you'll need to check them.